# geopandas dataframe to json

Tags: bigdata, geojson, geopandas

I have a geodataframe called `SchooolDistrictDf` that has more than 19,814,822 rows and looks like the following:

```
FIPS    SrcName crate_code  geohash ncessch sLevel  schnam  shape   stAbbrev
0   13820.0 NaN birmingh    djfjrrw 010000700091    1   TRACE CROSSINGS ELEM SCH    {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-86.85997...   AL
1   13820.0 NaN birmingh    djfjq2v 010000700091    1   TRACE CROSSINGS ELEM SCH    {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-86.90528...   AL
2   13820.0 NaN birmingh    djfjx17 010000700091    1   TRACE CROSSINGS ELEM SCH    {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-86.87507...   AL
3   13820.0 NaN birmingh    djfjx26 010000700091    1   TRACE CROSSINGS ELEM SCH    {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-86.86546...   AL
4   13820.0 NaN birmingh    djfm8rd 010000700091    1   TRACE CROSSINGS ELEM SCH    {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-86.82151...   AL
```

I was told that I need to convert/save it as a json. I'm not familiar with json but I tried doing the following on a small subset of the data:

```
SchooolDistrictDf.geometry.__geo_interface__
```

but I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.
```

is this because my `shape` column is in the following format

```
`{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-86.8599700927734, 33.3084869384766]}`
```

moreover, how could I convert a large geodataframe to json? I'd greatly appreciate any help

---

Edit:

This is how I tried getting the `SchooolDistrictDf['shape']` into normal geopandas geometry:

```
SchooolDistrictDf = pd.concat([SchooolDistrictDf.drop(['shape'], axis=1), SchooolDistrictDf['shape'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in SchooolDistrictDf['coordinates']]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4269'}
SchooolDistrictDf = GeoDataFrame(SchooolDistrictDf, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
SchooolDistrictDf = SchooolDistrictDf.drop(['coordinates','type'], axis=1)
SchooolDistrictDf =SchooolDistrictDf.to_crs(epsg=4269)
```

Comment: your geometry column needs `shapely` objects, not geojson-like dictionaries

Comment: (and the geometry column *must* be labeled `"geometry"`)

Comment: @PaulH  , thank you for your feedback! I tried converting `SchooolDistrictDf['shape']` into a `shapely` object called `geometry` (see edit above) however my current approach is not computationally efficient. Do you know a better way to convert the geojson shape into a a shapely geometry?

Comment: You can convert it more easily to a GeoDataFrame by doing `SchooolDistrictDf['geometry'] = SchooolDistrictDf['shapes'].apply(shapely.geometry.shape)`

Comment: @joris thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately when I tried that it gave me the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: Then that means that column is probably a string. You will have to convert it to an actual dict (eg using `eval` on each item)